# Camparação de bases de dados

Tags: oracle, mongodb, elasticsearch, big-data

Recebo diariamente uma base de dados Oracle com 12 tabelas contendo em média 8 milhões de registros cada.

Preciso tratá-la para pegar somente os registros atualizados do dia comparado à base do dia anterior, mas não tenho nenhum campo como "atualizado_em", que indique quais registros tratar.

Só que preciso fazer isso de uma forma mais rápida.

Estou estudando algumas abordagem com Pentaho Data Integration, ElasticSearch e o próximo seria algo com MongoDB, mas não cheguei a uma solução concreta ainda.

Alguém poderia me indicar ferramenta ou método, para trabalhar esse volume de dados?

Comment: Lendo por cima da experiência que eu tenho seria algo para gerar um histórico podendo ser mesmo em um banco no nosql contendo uma chave composta contendo a data + chave primária do item em questão que gera o valor da mudança. Creio que isso ele pode matar dois coelhos com um pau só e além disso no momento da leitura ele não vincula leitura a tabelas importante para o negócio.

Comment: A base do dia tem os registros da do dia anterior ? Cada dia dd 12 mi é guardado ?

Comment: Sim. Todos os dias é gerado um dump das tabelas originais e disponibilizado para mim.